# Set flatpickr text when date is 0000-00-00

Tags: jquery, flatpickr

I'm using flatpickr to change and set dates.

When i have a date that is not set: 0000-00-00, flatpickr shows: -1-11-30
How can i change that to be: 0000-00-00 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add option like this

```
minDate: "2000-01-01"
```

so -1-11-30 will be hidden